# How do I play private video by Android YouTubePlayer?

Tags: android, api, youtube, youtube-api

I ran Android YouTubePlayer API examples.
[YouTubePlayer API Example](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/)
But, I want to know how to play private video by YouTubePlayer API.

Is it possible?

Comment: Private video?...
according to privacy status

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to play **private** videos?

Comment: don't blame he would love to play private video

Comment: I have some private youtube videos about my son. I want to see that videos anywhere by my smartphone. But I can't find how to see private video by YouTubePlayer.

Comment: i appreciate Programming for personal work i do the same use my own small soft rather than others

Comment: Default youtube player shows limitly uploaded items. So I can't see all my uploaded items.